# How to disable git Prompt message for merge

Tags: git, github

I am using git command to pull the repository on Linux machine.When I do the git pull it prompt me for Commit message like

`Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch`

How can I disable this prompt message using my existing git pull command?

Following is the git command that I am using

`sudo git pull https://someusername:somepassword@someproject.visualstudio.com/BE%20SWM/_git/jcibe-swm-ems develop`

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to disable it, but it can be avoided for sure.

Comment: Okay, Please let me know how can I Avoid it. Also, the changes that are done in Local are just the logs that get build. So if its loss I am fine with it

Comment: if it just logs then you can do `git stash && git pull` in your terminal.

Comment: It seems the message is sent by a hook. Do you have a `post-merge` or `prepare-commit-msg` hook in the repo? They are usually under `.git/hooks/`, or under the path if `core.hooksPath=some_path` is specified by `git config`.

Answer (score 1):

What does `git pull` do is `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Here is solution to avoid prompt message.

```
git fetch https://someusername:somepassword@someproject.visualstudio.com/BE%20SWM/_git/jcibe-swm-ems develop && git merge FETCH_HEAD --no-edit
```

Comment: `sudo git pull https://someusername:somepassword@someproject.visualstudio.com/BE%20SWM/_git/jcibe-swm-ems develop --no-edit` Will it solve the problem

Comment: No, `sudo git fetch https://someusername:somepassword@someproject.visualstudio.com/BE%20SWM/_git/jcibe-swm-ems develop && git merge FETCH_HEAD --no-edit`
updated the answer.